# Is it possible to divide a pseudorandom

Tags: java, random, random-seed

I need to distribute a Java system that uses pseudorandoms. Each node of the system must process a certain ammount of randoms.

The results must be reproducible, so the randoms must depend on a seed as a parameter.

```
Random random = new Random(long seed);
```

For example, if I need to process 100 randoms and I have 2 nodes, the first node must process from 1 to 50 and the second from 51 to 100.

The problem is that pseudorandoms need to iterate over themselves in order to produce the same sequence of randoms everytime (for the same seed).

In the previous example, is there a way to start the generation of randoms in the second node from the 51th random? (Thus, avoiding the need to generate and trash randoms from 1 to 50 in this node).

Comment: Not particularly.  You'd be better off figuring out another scheme for how to divide the random numbers between the nodes, e.g. two nodes would use every other random number rather than the first 50 and the last 50.  Do you need it to be reproducible even if you change the number of nodes?  If not that could make things lots easier, by keying other `Random` instances with seeds generated by the first `Random`.

Comment: Hmm... this wouldn't solve my problem as each node would have to process to the 100th random anyways.

Comment: Dont use pseudorandom sequences, use instead a hash function. The first node will process the hashes of 1..50, the second will process the hashes of 51..100

Comment: How is it not a solution? A particular node skipping some inputs is not the same as processing every input.

Comment: Because the process isn't very complex. The complexity of the problem is the amount of randoms that must be generated. For example, 500'000.000.

Answer (score 0):

What about `random.nextInt(50) + 50`?

You can use the same seed, on the one node you do "+ 0" on the other you do "+ 50".

If you do not like that you will get now the same sequence on both nodes just off by 50, you could construct a seed per node from a random generator using the same seed.

i.e.

Node 1:

```
Random seedGenerator = new Random(globalSeed)
Random myRandom = new Random(seedGenerator.nextInt())
int something = myRandom.nextInt(50)
```

Node 2:

```
Random seedGenerator = new Random(globalSeed)
seedGenerator.nextInt() // node 1's seed
Random myRandom = new Random(seedGenerator.nextInt())
int something = myRandom.nextInt(50) + 50
```

node 1 will give you ints between 0 and 50, node two between 50 and 100.

Comment: The problem with this strategy is that if I need to change the amount of nodes that process the randoms, it wouldn't work. What would I do then with a third node? I would have to add, for example, +100 to the random. And then the seq of randoms from 1 to 100 wouldn't be the same.

Comment: I don't read this as wanting _numbers_ between 0 and 50, but rather requiring the first 50 numbers the `Random` would generate and the second `50` numbers the `Random` would generate.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an alternate way to generate a pseudorandom sequence: Consider using a hash function (of type integer -> integer) instead, and allpy it to the natural numbers, so the items in the sequence would be `hash(0), hash(1), hash(2)` instead of `seed, step(seed), step(step(seed))`. This way you can access the `i`th element in the pseudorandom sequence in `O(1)`, and can distribute the workload as you want.